# Is there any way I can hide the WPBakery Page Builder tab for other roles except admin

Tags: php, wordpress, wpbakery

I am trying to hide the WPBakery Page Builder tab for all the roles except admin.

**I tried using adminimize plugin to do so, but still the tab is visible in all the roles.** https://wordpress.org/plugins/adminimize/

I also tried the below code but I can only do it for admin and not other roles.

```
if ( !is_admin() ) {
    function custom_menu_page_removing() 
    {
    remove_menu_page('vc-general'); //vc
    }
add_action( 'admin_init', 'custom_menu_page_removing' );
}
```

Comment: Do you need to code it? There is an option in WP Bakery menu Under Role Manager to disable it for other roles and post types.

Comment: @xDiff Actually I wanted to code it, so even if the admin checks from the role manager, they should not be able to play with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**vc-welcome** will hide menu from all other roles except admin so no need to write if condition, You can try below code

```
function custom_menu_page_removing() {
    remove_menu_page('vc-welcome');
    }
add_action( 'admin_init', 'custom_menu_page_removing' );
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a better way to do this straight from the WPBakery Page Builder Settings. You can follow the menu from the image below and set the Settings options to disabled.

[WPBakery Page Builder > Role Manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YZkJs.jpg)

Comment: I tried this, but cannot found any solution to hide that specific tab. I had to do it with manual code.